# fadeOut() and fadeIn() in the same action

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

i'm trying to use JQuery to make a languaje selection nav and, once selected, fade out that nav at the same time i display a second nav using fade in.

This is my markup

```
div id="content">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
        <ul id="navLang">
            <li><a href="#" id="EN">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="ES">Español</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="navEng"> 
            <ul >
                <li><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Campaign</a></li>           
                <li><a href="#">Editorial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div id="navEs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Belleza</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Campañas</a></li>           
                <li><a href="#">Editorial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Biografía</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

and this is my script

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#navEng").hide();
    $("#navEs").hide();
    $("#EN").click(function(){
        $("#navLang").fadeOut("slow");
        $("navEng").fadeIn("Slow");
    });
    $("#ES").click(function(){
        $("#navLang").fadeOut("slow");
        $("navEs").fadeIn("Slow");
    });
});
```

The fade out effect works well, but i can't make the second nav to fade in, i've tried using display:none; before as well but id didn't worked neither..

basically, when i hide the navs using display:none; i cant make them to fade in and when i use .hide() they wont hide.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("#navEs")` instead of `$("navEs")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to select elements by id you need to include `#` in your selectors, that is, `$("#navEng")` instead of `$("navEng")` (and so forth):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#navEng").hide();
    $("#navEs").hide();
    $("#EN").click(function(){
        $("#navLang").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#navEng").fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $("#ES").click(function(){
        $("#navLang").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#navEs").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

EDIT: Note that JavaSript is case sensitive, so you should say `"slow"` with a lowercase "s", not `"Slow"` (`.fadeIn()` will default to 400ms if you pass a string it doesn't recognise). And it would probably be a more pleasing effect if you didn't start the fade in until the fade out is finished:

```
    $("#navLang").fadeOut("slow", function() {
       $("#navEng").fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vmECd/

Comment: In your edit of the question you only fixed some of the missing `#` selectors - you didn't fix the ones on the `.fadeIn()` lines.

Comment: worked, i can't believe i didn't see it, must be the late hour... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#navLang").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#navEng").fadeIn("Slow"); // apply "#"
```

and can do by better way
like below

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#navEng,#navEs").hide();
    $("#EN").click(function(){
    $("#navLang").fadeOut("slow",function(){  
    $("#navEng").fadeIn("Slow"); // apply "#"
    });

    });
  $("#ES").click(function(){
    $("#navLang").fadeOut("slow",function(){  
    $("#navEs").fadeIn("Slow"); // apply "#"
    });
});

});
```

reference **[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)** ,**[fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)**